# Разные версии модулей в одном проекте

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, qtquick

Есть две версии Qt5:

- /home/user/.Qt/ - qt5.6 без webkit&webengine (интернал еррор при сборке)
- /home/user/.Qt/Qt5.5/gnu... полный пак, с установщика.

Возможно ли в одном проекте использовать вебкит\вебенжин (5.5 соответственно) и qtmultimedia-5.6 (Qbs проект)? Либо как-то установить qtmultimedia5.6 как 5.5(пересобрать мб)?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете взять любые библиотеки, заголовочные файлы и исходники из 5.6 и включить их к себе в проект скопировав в папку своего проекта на Qt 5.5.